# Twig sort function, sorting numbers low-high

Tags: twig

Im trying to use the twig |sort function but find it rather confusing to figure out how to sort with numbers ranging lowest to highest.

**Documentation:** https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/sort.html

**My code example:**

```
{% for duel in group %}
    {% duel.intvalue %}
{% endfor %}
```

Where intvalue is the data needing sorting

Can anyone help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the documentation is clear enough.

let say you have array of object users

```
{
    "users" : [
        {
            "name": "third",
            "age": 29
        },
        {
            "name": "first",
            "age": 2
        },
        {
            "name": "first",
            "age": 2
        },
        {
            "name": "second",
            "age": 28
        }
    ]
}
```

1. sort your data by name

```
{% for user in users|sort %}
    {{ user.name }}, 
{% endfor %}
```

2. sort your data by age

```
{% for user in users|sort %}
    {{ user.age }}, 
{% endfor %}
```

3. sort data by age and show its name

```
{% for user in users|sort((a, b) => a.age <=> b.age) %}
    {{ user.name }}, 
{% endfor %}
```

https://twigfiddle.com/tca0vz

Comment: Hey thanks, yes the documentation is clear but I guess I needed some clarification thank you for this detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

A working example would be:

```
{# setup the expample #}
{% set group = [{intvalue:5},{intvalue:1},{intvalue:4},{intvalue:3},{intvalue:2}] %}

{% for duel in group|sort((a, b) => a.intvalue <=> b.intvalue) %}
    {{ duel.intvalue }}
{% endfor %}
```

Or see this fiddle: https://twigfiddle.com/ru1gpd

Comment: This would be good if I were to have a set number of values but I can't know beforehand how many intvalues ill have thank you though.

Comment: This is just an example and will work with every amount of intvalues ;)

Comment: Just for my clarification and any future readers then: I can {% set group = Intvalues %} and it should work?